# Go through a number of functions in Python

Tags: python

I have an unknown number of functions in my python script (well, it is known, but not constant) that start with site_...
I was wondering if there's a way to go through all of these functions in some main function that calls for them.
something like:

```
foreach function_that_has_site_ as coolfunc
   if coolfunc(blabla,yada) == true:
      return coolfunc(blabla,yada)
```

so it would go through them all until it gets something that's true.

thanks!

Comment: Note that you might be better off trying to do this a different way - for instance, instead of defining all of them as top-level functions named `site_ZZZZ`, instead store them as a list or dict of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `inspect` module, already mentioned in other answers, is especially handy because you get to easily *filter* the names and values of objects you care about.  [inspect.getmembers](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect.getmembers#inspect.getmembers) takes *two* arguments: the object whose members you're exploring, and a *predicate* (a function returning `bool`) which will accept (return `True` for) only the objects you care about.

To get "the object that is this module" you need the following well-known idiom:

```
import sys
this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
```

In your predicate, you want to select only objects which are functions and have names that start with `site_`:

```
import inspect
def function_that_has_site(f):
    return inspect.isfunction(f) and f.__name__.startswith('site_')
```

With these two items in hand, your loop becomes:

```
for n, coolfunc in inspect.getmembers(this_module, function_that_has_site):
   result = coolfunc(blabla, yada)
   if result: return result
```

I have also split the loop body so that each function is called only once (which both saves time *and* is a safer approach, avoiding possible side effects)... as well as rewording it in Python;-)

Comment: http://codepad.org/gq4ZYJPJ

getting 
  result = funcme()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @asaf, my bad -- I had a typo in the `for` loop (it needs to get the name and function separately).  Edited & fixed it now, adding the `n,` part.

Comment: added n, error:
result = funcme()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: ok just had to add if n.startswith(...) because for some reason it returns more than just the functions that start the parameter.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the inspect module?

http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

The following will return the methods:

```
inspect.getmembers
```

Then you could invoke with:

```
methodobjToInvoke = getattr(classObj, methodName) 
methodobj("arguments")
```

Answer (score 1):

This method goes through all properties of the current module and executes all functions it finds with a name starting with `site_`:

```
import sys
import types
for elm in dir():
    f = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], elm)
    if isinstance(f, types.FunctionType) and f.__name__[:5] == "site_":
        f()
```

The function-type check is unnecessary if only functions are have names starting with `site_`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def run():
    for f_name, f in globals().iteritems():
        if not f_name.startswith('site_'):
            continue
        x = f()
        if x:
            return x
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use a decorator to enumerate the functions you care about:

```
_funcs = []

def enumfunc(func):
  _funcs.append(func)
  return func

@enumfunc
def a():
  print 'foo'

@enumfunc
def b():
  print 'bar'

@enumfunc
def c():
  print 'baz'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for f in _funcs:
    f()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir), [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals). Or [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module (as mentioned above).

```
def site_foo():
  pass

def site_bar():
  pass

for name, f in globals().items():
  if name.startswith("site_"):
    print name, f()
```